# Google Maps doesn't shows the zoomControl

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Map initialize-Code:

```
function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: <? print $zoom; ?>,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.55961, 7.58061),
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

Unfortunately the ZoomControl doesn't it doesn't shows the ZoomControl-Elements on the site:  http://www.paediatrica.ch/www/inhalt_de.php?MAIN_RUB_ID=377

What is wrong? Thanks for help

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: There are [known issues with prototype.js](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7067), I see (two copies of) this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the Chrome javascript console on your page.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Comment: Moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: <?php echo ($zoom) ? $zoom : 4; ?>,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.55961, 7.58061),
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

Comment: i tried your code, but it doesn't show the ZoomControl. it has to be on something other

Comment: have you tried the code without any PHP? zoom: 4

Does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

You are using prototype.js.

There are [known issues with prototype.js](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7067), I see (two copies of) this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in the Chrome javascript console on your page.